# Python Text Based Map

Tags: python, string, text, dictionary, python-2.5

When It comes to graphics, my programming skills have never been that great so I resort to using text in my games or programs. I was wondering if anyone knew how to take different values  from a list and print it out in a game map so it will display a grid of text sort of like this game from the 1980's: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(text_game)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_%28text_game%29)
The idea is that the player can input 'left', 'right', 'up', and 'down' to move their symbol around. It would need to redraw the map after every  action. I was also wondering if anyone knew a way to clear the text in the python shell or a DOS window (depending on your preferred method of running programs) so it would appear that the map isn't just being redrawn over and over again. Sorry its a lot to ask. I would greatly appreciate your answer.

Comment: Please try something before asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

use a package like `curses` to get 'direct' access to the text-screen. You have absolute positioning, colors, scrolling and of cause clearing.